# How does an onclick funktion work, how do I get php informations to javascript, how do I get javascript informations to php and how do I use ajax js?

Tags: javascript, php, variables, onclick

I try to use an onclick function. If the user clicks the html button a js function should be done. For this function I need some variables of the php code. How do I get them?
If I get them I have to change them. So how do I got them (the changed variables) to php?
I thought that ajax could perhaps help me. But how do I use ajax?

Comment: there are plenty of tutorials of how to use basic ajax - this is way too broad a question for SO. Sorry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using a library like [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) or [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) might help, compared to using Javascript's `fetch` function. Here's how you might achieve that using jQuery:

HTML

```html
<button onClick="handleClick()">Click me<button>
```

Javascript

```
function handleClick() {
  console.log('Clicked the button')
    $.get('path/to/script.php', function (data) {
    // It helps if the data returned in the PHP script is JSON formatted
    console.log(data)
  });
}
```